# Understanding the most basic example in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am fairly (very) new to learning web applications with experience in Object Oriented design with C/C++/Java. I am trying to learn [Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) with typescript and I am following the example [here](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html)

Relevant snippet (slightly modified with further steps in the example)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero}} details!</h2>'
})
export class AppComponent
{
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    hero = 'Windstorm';
}
```

I am wondering how Angular knows where to look for to (as I understand, bind) the {{title}} in the html tag. I think some stuff is implicit.

Does angular simply look for any members, or fields within the scope? Is there an implicit "this" i.e (this.title). In my experiments, it seems that this does not have any negative effect, but my IDE is telling me theres an "unresolved variable or type this" How does it know to look in AppComponent? Is it because of `declarations: [ AppComponent ],}`? (See app.module.ts)

Is this related to the $scope concept from Angular2?

Is the order here important? i.e. the @Component is a decorator of the exported class?

Please feel free to correct my terminology.

Comment: I just started learning Angular2 about three days ago but from what I gather, the variables within  the component are there for the taking within {{}}. You can also look through arrays with *ngFor and display the values within the array.

Comment: And yes, @Component is the decorator of the exported class.

Comment: that makes more sense now. It was not clear to me that the order of `@Component` followed by export matter. I wonder then, if the export keyword is optional, if it would ever make sense to decorate a class that is not exported. My gut tells it would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to know that in Angular2 everything is a Component, a Component is a set of a class, it's template and some metadata. The metadata contains information about the Component and how it can be applied, etc.

The metadata is specified using a Decorator. Decorators are annotations written on the Component class

**Question 1**: I am wondering how Angular knows where to look for to (as I understand, bind) the {{title}} in the HTML tag. I think some stuff is implicit.

**Answer**: Angular looks for properties, objects and methods on the Component class, how does it know to look over there, it is because of the `@Component` decorator

**Question 2**: Is this related to the $scope concept from Angular2?

**Answer**: Angular2 uses the `this` syntax i.e. similar to `controller as` syntax in Angular 1.x it doesn't have things like `$scope` and `$rootScope`

**Question 3**: Is the order here important? i.e. the @Component is a decorator of the exported class?

**Answer**: Yes the order here is important, the @Component which is a Decorator is nothing but a function which should be invoked to decorate the Component class in order to specify the metadata.

So where ever you use the selector `<my-app></my-app>` as a Nested Component or as a Root Component then Angular2 will use the given template and map it to the specified Component class that's how data-binding works with given properties and functions.